# React/TypeScript: Union Types in state of Context API

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TypeScript does not seem to be recognizing that property `state.recipes` do exist when I use the state in some other component, this would be the case if `YummlyState` is the type of `RecipesState`. I suspect the `YummlyState` to always be the type of `InitialState` because that is the type it will have initially because of the initial state being set.

Also to include, is there anything else you notice about this Context which you think should be different?

Many thanks!

```
import React, {
    createContext,
    Dispatch,
    PropsWithChildren,
    ReactElement,
    Reducer,
    useContext,
    useReducer,
} from 'react'

//  Recipe
export type Recipe = {
    id: number
    title: string
    image: string
    readyInMinutes: number
    diets: string[]
    pricePerServing: number
    servings: number
}

// Response
export type SpoonacularResponse = {
    number: number
    offset: number
    results: Recipe[]
    totalResults: number
}

// Yummly State
type StatusUnion = 'resolved' | 'rejected' | 'idle' | 'pending'

type InitialState = {
    status: StatusUnion
}

type SingleRecipeState = InitialState & {
    recipe: Recipe
}

type RecipesState = InitialState & {
    recipes: Recipe[]
}

type ErrorState = InitialState & {
    error: unknown
}

type YummlyState = InitialState | SingleRecipeState | RecipesState | ErrorState

// Action Union Type for the reducer
type Action =
    | { type: 'pending' }
    | { type: 'singleRecipeResolved'; payload: Recipe }
    | { type: 'recipesResolved'; payload: Recipe[] }
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    | { type: 'rejected'; payload: unknown }

// The initial state
const initialState: YummlyState = {
    status: 'idle',
}

//  The Reducer
function yummlyReducer(state: YummlyState, action: Action): YummlyState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'pending':
            return {
                status: 'pending',
            }
        case 'singleRecipeResolved':
            return {
                ...state,
                status: 'resolved',
                recipe: action.payload,
            }
        case 'recipesResolved':
            return {
                ...state,
                status: 'resolved',
                recipes: action.payload,
            }
        case 'rejected':
            return {
                ...state,
                status: 'rejected',
                error: action.payload,
            }
        default:
            throw new Error('This should not happen :D')
    }
}

type YummlyContextType = {
    state: YummlyState
    dispatch: Dispatch<Action>
}

const YummlyContext = createContext<YummlyContextType>({
    state: initialState,
    dispatch: () => {},
})

YummlyContext.displayName = 'YummlyContext'

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
function YummlyProvider(props: PropsWithChildren<{}>): ReactElement {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<YummlyState, Action>>(
        yummlyReducer,
        initialState
    )
    const value = { state, dispatch }
    return <YummlyContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}

function useYummlyContext(): YummlyContextType {
    const context = useContext(YummlyContext)
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error(`No provider for YummlyContext given`)
    }
    return context
}

export { YummlyProvider, useYummlyContext }
```

Comment: Since the context value is a union of multiple state types, you have to check that your value is the success type before accessing properties that only exist on the success type.

Comment: I would define the union a bit differently so that you can use the value of status to figure out the rest.  Read up on on “discriminated unions”.  I can leave an answer in a bit.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Ok, Thanks for your answer. I will read upon it, but very much would appreciate your answer :D! Thanks again!

Comment: @LindaPaiste Do you mean something like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions, prettier does not seem to like the first |, also it still does not seem to be working :c

Comment: Yes that doc page is exactly what I meant.  Though after looking at your code more closely, the discriminated union isn't perfect here because you have two different types of `success` responses.  I just left a lengthy answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with a union, you will not be able to access a property such as `state.recipes` unless that property has been declared on **ALL** members of the union.  There are essentially two ways that you can deal with this type of thing:

1. Check that the property key exists before trying to access it.  If it exists, we know it is a valid value and not `undefined`.
2. Include a base interface in the `YummlyState` union which says that all of the keys of any of the members can be accessed, but their values might be `undefined`.

#### Guarding Properties

Without changing your type definitions, the simplest thing you can do is use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) to see if a property exists.  Based on your union, typescript knows that if there is a property `recipes`, it must be of type `Recipe[]`.

```
const Test = () => {
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(YummlyContext);
    if ( 'recipes' in state ) {
        // do something with recipes
        const r: Recipe[] = state.recipes;
    }
}
```

#### Declaring Optional Properties

The base interface that we want to include in our union looks like this:

```
interface YummlyBase {
    status: StatusUnion;
    recipe?: Recipe;
    recipes?: Recipe[];
    error?: unknown;
}
```

`status` is required, but all other properties are optional.  This means that we can always access them, but they might be `undefined`.  So you need to check that a particular value is not `undefined` before using it.

We are able to destructure the object, which is nice:

```
const base: YummlyBase = { status: 'idle' };

const {status, recipe, recipes, error} = base;
```

Using just the `YummlyBase` alone is ok, but it doesn't give us all of the information.  It's better if `YummlyState` is the base **and** a union of specific members.

```
type YummlyState = YummlyBase & (InitialState | SingleRecipeState | RecipesState | ErrorState)
```

#### Discriminating Unions

Each of your scenarios has a different string literal for `status` (well, mostly), but we haven't made use of that fact.  [Discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) is a way to narrow the type of the object based on the value of a string property like `status`.

You are already doing this with your `Action` union type.  When you `switch` based on `action.type`, it knows the correct type for `action.payload`.

This can be extremely helpful in some situations.  It is less helpful here because the status `resolved` is used by both `SingleRecipeState` and `RecipesState`, so you still need additional checking.  That's why I've put this option last.

```
type InitialState = {
  status: 'idle' | 'pending';
}

type SingleRecipeState = {
  status: 'resolved';
  recipe: Recipe
}

type RecipesState = {
  status: 'resolved';
  recipes: Recipe[];
}

type ErrorState = {
  status: 'rejected';
  error: unknown;
}

type YummlyState = InitialState | SingleRecipeState | RecipesState | ErrorState

type StatusUnion = YummlyState['status'];

const check = (state: YummlyState) => {
  if (state.status === 'rejected') {
    // state is ErrorState
    state.error;
  }
  if ( state.status === 'resolved' ) {
    // state is RecipesState or SingleRecipeState
    state.recipe; // still an error because we don't know if it's single or multiple
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/OwEeyw)

Comment: Thank you! Right now I check if "recipes" is in the state using ternary operator, if so then I just map it out and return the recipes :D.